# Proving the function $ f\left( x\right) =\dfrac{1-\lambda ^{x}}{x}$ is downward sloping

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

\begin{aligned}f\left( x\right) =\dfrac{1-\lambda ^{x}}{x}\\
u=\dfrac{1}{x},v=1-\lambda ^{x}\\
u'=-\dfrac{1}{x^{2}},v'=-\lambda ^{x}\ln \lambda \\
f'\left( x\right) =-\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}\left( 1-\lambda ^{x}\right) +\dfrac{1}{x}\left( -\lambda ^{x}\ln \lambda \right) \\
=\dfrac{\lambda ^{x}-1-\lambda ^{x}x\ln \lambda }{x^{2}}\\
\lambda ^{x}x\ln \lambda  >\lambda ^{x}-1?\end{aligned}

I have got this far but can’t prove the last inequality. I have to use the fact that $x>0$ and lambda is in between $0$ and $1$. How can use that fact that $\ln(x)<x-1$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\lambda ^{ - x}  = e^{ - x\ln \lambda }  > 1 - x\ln \lambda .
$$
Multiplying through by $\lambda^x$, we find
$$
1 > \lambda ^x  - \lambda ^x x\ln \lambda ,
$$
i.e.,
$$
\lambda ^x x\ln \lambda > \lambda ^x  - 1 .
$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $u= x \ln\lambda $ then your inequality is equivalent to

$$ue^u>e^u-1 $$

when $u<0$.

You can rewrite it as

$$e^{-u}>1-u$$

which is true.

Comment: It should be $e^{-u}>1-u$.

Comment: yes thanks @Gary for the catch ! My answer is the inverse of yours :D